# WinForms.Show() - "Error Creating Window Handle" - NOT using up handles

Tags: c#, winforms

All the answers on here about this error message being shown when I call `.Show()` on a .NET WinForms dialog indicate that too many handles are being used.

I am getting this error and at the time if I look in TaskManager I see:

> FrapiDriver.EXE: Handles 250, Threads 13, USERs 1303, GDIs 102.

Nowhere near my 10,000 limit.

Does anyone know of other causes for this issue? I'd be happy if I can just suppress the error message because this isn't stopping my program from functioning (I can 'Continue' and everything works fine).

Comment: Please read the following link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/08/07/cannot-create-window-handle-desktop-heap.aspx

Comment: Good info but it's a little out of date. Thanks. Is there a version of dheapmon that works on Windows 7?

Comment: Dheapmon is not designed to work with Windows 7 and has compatibility issues. You can  attempt to install the program in Compatibility Mode (Windows XP).

Comment: That would normally suggest that the OS limitations the program was checking for you no longer exist. I've had no luck installing it even in compatibility mode.